# countability of polynomials in 2 variables with nonnegative rational coefficients of degree at most 2

Tags: real-analysis

How do I go with the proof that the set $P_{2,\mathbb{Q}}(x, y)$ of polynomials in variables $x, y$ with nonnegative rational coefficients of degree at most 2 is countable?

So the polynomials are determined by the rational coefficients:

$P_{2,\mathbb{Q}}(x, y)=\{c_0+c_1x+c_2y+c_3xy+c_4x^2+c_5y^2:c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,c_5 \in \mathbb{Q}\}$

We know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, so $\mathbb{Q}^6$ is countable as the cartesian product of a finite number of countable sets. Now note that $|P_{2,\mathbb{Q}}(x, y)| = |\mathbb{Q}^6|$. Therefore $P_{2,\mathbb{Q}}(x, y)$ is countable. Are there any corrections to my solution?

Comment: Your solution is fine.

Comment: Is not the set of all polynomials of a finite many of variables with rational coefficients, countable?